# Send email after user delete account (before_destroy) in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm kinda new to ruby, so my problem is I'm trying to send an email after user creation, update and deletion.

It works for create and update, I do receive confirmation's email, but it doesn't work for the `destroy`, maybe because I'm not properly using the callback `before_destroy`.

my model `user.rb` :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    after_create :welcome_send
    before_destroy :goodbye_user, prepend: true
    after_update :update_user

    def welcome_send
        UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_now
    end

    def goodbye_user
        UserMailer.bye_email(self).deliver_now
    end

    def update_user
        UserMailer.update_info(self).deliver_now
    end
end
```

and my `user_mailer` is :

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'no-reply@monsite.fr'

    def welcome_email(user)
      @user = user 
      @url  = 'http://monsite.fr/login' 
      mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Bienvenue dans la team  !') 
    end

    def bye_email(user)
        @user = user
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'A bientôt !') 
    end

    def update_info(user)
        @user = user
        @url = 'http://monsite.fr/login'
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Modification de vos paramètres')
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's *extremely* bad idea to use model callbacks for sending emails. I'd suggest moving the mailers-related stuff to the controllers layer instead...

Answer (score 0):

As @konstantin-strukov suggests, you should avoid using callbacks, especially for sending emails. You are out of the scope of what a Model is supposed to do in MVC, i.e interacting with the database.

You could move this in the controller, for instance :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def destroy
    UserMailer.bye_email(@user).deliver_now
    @user.destroy!

    redirect_to ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that it is your delete method and not your callback that doesn't work. Just try to replace it by 'destroy', and it should work fine.